# Get milliseconds value from bundle and pass it to countdowntimer Java/Android

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

This is what i am doing at the moment. I am getting the value(in miliseconds) from another activity in my current activity like below

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        final long getTimeInMili=extras.getLong("timeInMiliSeconds",0);
        Log.e("Got Time in mili : ", ""+getTimeInMili);
```

Then ,I am using the countdownTimer class like below

```
final CounterClass countDownTimer = new CounterClass(getTimeInMili, 1000);
countDownTimer.start();
```

And this is my CounterClass

```
public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

    /**
     * @param millisInFuture    The number of millis in the future from the call
     *                          to {@link #start()} until the countdown is done and {@link #onFinish()}
     *                          is called.
     * @param countDownInterval The interval along the way to receive
     *                          {@link #onTick(long)} callbacks.
     */
    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
        );
        Log.e("Timer", hms);
        timer.setText(hms);

    }
```

I did some logging and the problem seems to be that the value of getTimeinMili changes to zero once onTick is executed. So my question is

1. Why does the value of the getTimeinMili changes?
2. How to make how to correctly pass getTimeinMili to the CounterClass?

Comment: how do you put your `timeInMiliSeconds` into your bundle pls ?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OnRideTimerActivity.class);             intent.putExtra("timeInMiliSeconds",diffInTime);            startActivity(intent);

Comment: Ok and your log `Log.e("Got Time in mili : ", ""+getTimeInMili);` return the correct value ?

Comment: Yes it does , but the problem is after the countdowntimer executes, for some reason the Log line is again getting executed which it shouldn't and this time it gets the value 0, since its not coming from any activity. Please help if you can. @HugoMallet

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why it's not work properly with your code :(

Comment: I have solved this issue, actually it was being created since there were 2 intents which were passing strings to this activity. And when the bundle = getIntent.getExtras() was called inside on create it was called twice and hence the second time was returning a null value.